# Twiddle Standalone not working

Tags: wildfly-8

We are using Twiddle standalone https://developer.jboss.org/people/arnoldjohansson/blog/2012/04/14/twiddle-standalone for JMX Monitoring in Wildfly 8.2.As per the readme instructions,We have downloaded the zip file provided in the link https://github.com/swesource/twiddle-standalone and set the JBOSS_HOME in twiddle.sh.When i start the wildfly server using standalone.sh and try to run the below command

twiddle.sh -s service:jmx:remoting-jmx://127.0.0.1:9999 get java.lang:type=ClassLoading

Iam getting error as below :

```
19:18:22,209 INFO  [xnio] XNIO version 3.3.0.Final
19:18:22,277 INFO  [nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.0.Final
19:18:22,318 INFO  [remoting] JBoss Remoting version 4.0.6.Final
19:18:22,534 ERROR [Twiddle] Exec failed
org.jboss.util.NestedRuntimeException: Connection refused; - nested throwable: (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused)
    at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle$1.getServer(Twiddle.java:221)
    at org.jboss.console.twiddle.command.MBeanServerCommand.getMBeanServer(MBeanServerCommand.java:64)
    at org.jboss.console.twiddle.command.GetCommand.execute(GetCommand.java:149)
    at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle.main(Twiddle.java:370)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread$ConnectHandle.handleReady(WorkerThread.java:319)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:539)
    at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:272)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:253)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:351)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:335)
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnector.internalRemotingConnect(RemotingConnector.java:232)
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnector.internalConnect(RemotingConnector.java:151)
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnector.connect(RemotingConnector.java:102)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:268)
    at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle.createMBeanServerConnection(Twiddle.java:322)
    at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle.connect(Twiddle.java:331)
    at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle.access$400(Twiddle.java:60)
    at org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle$1.getServer(Twiddle.java:217)
    ... 3 more
```

Can anyone suggest what would be the problem and help me with proper steps.

Comment: Hi Sunayana.. I am facing the same issue. Am migrating my app from JBoss 6 to Wildfly 8 and trying to identify an equivalent feature in Wildfly 8 like twiddle in JBoss 6 for managing MBeans (invoke MBean operations). Do you have any solution for this ?

Comment: Just adding that I tried twiddle standalone in Windows using twiddle.bat and I could connect fine. Please let me know whether you face the issue in Windows or Unix.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply.I was running it on Linux machine.